# permission denied when using su to execute a node program

Tags: linux, node.js, service, su

here is my node program

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('./data.txt', 'test');
```

it is in /home/test/ and the test directory 's privilege is rwxrwxrwx.
when i run node test.js with the tomcat account, the data.txt could be created.

but when i run a service to execute su tomcat -c 'node /home/test/test.js',
the data.txt could not be created and there is a permission denied hint in the stdout.

```
sudo service test
```

here is my service in /etc/init.d

```
su tomcat -c 'node /home/test/test.js'
```

can anyone tell me why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be several things.  For example, the current directory isn't /home/test when running from init.d.

I recommend piping the output of stderr and stdout to a log file to a specific (not relative) area that allows writing (e.g. /var/log).